# PHP DOMDocument XML

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, domdocument

I have a php variable like this:

```
<div class="classA">
    <a id="someID1"></a>
    <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <div class="class4">
                <h4>name, name<small>string</small></h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>number<small>string</small></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="classA">
    <a id="someID2"></a>
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">
            <div class="class3">
                <div class="class4">
                    <h4>nameA,nameA<small>stringA</small></h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>numberA<small>stringB</small></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the data from h4 which is in classA with  so name,name/number/stringA/stringB or something like that. 
How do I get this done with DOMDocument?

I don't have a clue how to do that because the only difference between these two classes is the a-tag.

Comment: show us what you've tried so we can help you on your way - read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In this case you want get 4 `h4`?

Comment: Yes I want to get h4 but only from the classA which contains <a id="someID2">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to selecting elements with special condition. In your case, base on child id attribute.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@class='classA' and a[@id='someID2']]")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("h4");
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/KmF2Q)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `getElementById($id)`:

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$a = $dom->getElementById('someID2');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the div using DOM then you must assign different class for the divs and you can do this:

```
    <div class="class1">
      <a id="someID1"></a>
      ... 
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
      <a id="someID2"></a>
      ... 
    </div>
```

then you can do:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('class2');
```

Comment: I get this string from an url so it is no option to manipulate the string